# async's future holds on to copies of arguments after async task completes

Tags: multithreading, c++11, asynchronous, future

Consider the scope

```
{
  std::shared_ptr<T> data = new T();
  std::future f = std::async(std::launch::async, operation, data);
  keep_for_later(std::move(f));
}
```

where `keep_for_later()` stores the future in a shoebox for a while, while the `operation()` completes fairly quickly.

I am seeing that the object of type `T` is not destroyed upon `operation()`'s return, but rather kept alive for an arbitrarily long time, as long as the `future` returned by the `async()` call is not destroyed.

Obviously, `async()` must copy its parameters, and hold these copies alive until the asynchronously invoked function returns. But it seems suboptimal to me that these copies are not destroyed as soon as the function is done, as would temporary arguments be destroyed in a normal synchronous function call (if I just called `operation(std::shared_ptr<T>(data))` instead of through `async()`, a temporary object would be created only for the lifetime of the call). Am I just dealing with a sloppy implementation?

Is there a C++11 portable way to prevent the association of the lifetime of temporary copies with the returned future?

If (as I suspect) there is none, is there an alternative `std::async()`-like implementation that does allow that (e. g. in Boost), that I can use portably with both Microsoft cl and gcc?

Comment: What's the signature of `operation`? Can you change it?

Comment: `void operation(std::shared_ptr<T>)`, and it can be anything I want. But the `T` is already managed through a ref-counted smart pointer, so there is not so much wiggle room. Do you have an idea?

Comment: If it is taking the `shared_ptr` by value, you shouldn't have this problem in a conforming implementation. Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb47a81653952111. Slightly modified, http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ also behaves correctly.

Comment: This is the VS2015 library, notoriously buggy. For one, `unique_ptr` or other non-copyable objects cannot be passed to async calls at all. Just ran your example in VS, and indeed got `Done sleeping\nGot future\nNoisy::~Noisy()` :( Still looking for a workaround.

Comment: @T.C.: wow, your sample does work in WebCompiler! At the bottom of page though: _The WebCompiler is a recent development build of the Visual C++ toolset (compiler and libraries),_ Looks like the issue is fixed, but apparently I am not getting it until VS2017+. Oh well....

Comment: You may be able to get it in Update 2.

Comment: @T.C.: Thanks, looks like it! This blog mentions that the toolset on WebCompiler is same as Update 2: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/01/22/vs-2015-update-2s-stl-is-c17-so-far-feature-complete/

Answer (score 0):

'data' is still alive within your function scope.... So, while async is running, there at least 2 copies.... If you want to prevent that, move 'data' into async

```
{
    std::shared_ptr<T> data = new T();
    std::future f = std::async(std::launch::async, operation, std::move(data));
   keep_for_later(std::move(f));
```

}

Comment: That is not the point of the question, and will not fix the problem. The point is after both this scope and operation's scope are exited, then the object is still alive. You *may* help one reference of the two die quicker (assuming shared_ptr optimized move), but it is the *second* reference somewhere in the guts of async plumbing that holds the object forever.

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that, just read the comments to your question.. seems you've resolved it. right?

Comment: Well, since I cannot get hold of the updated library yet, even a preview, and MS gives no ETA, it is possible I would still benefit if suggested a portable library that I can use in lieu of `std:async()`. Currently there is still time on my schedule to simply wait for the MSVS 2015 Update 2, but there is some degree of uncertainty until I get hold of it and confirm the fix. I would not frankly call the issue resolved--yet.